# NextJS with next-i18next and Firebase functions routes all pages to 404 when locale in url path

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, internationalization

I'm using `next-i18next` with Next.js (Deploying SSR to Firebase functions) and I followed the documentation here https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next

And it all fine in development mode, and even in production mode locally using `next start`, all pages works fine and routing to other locales works fine.

But when deployed to firebase functions (*also when running emulators*) all pages with locale specified in url `localhost/en` routes to 404, but `localhost/` works fine.

```
localhost/ --> works fine and shows locale 'ar'
localhost/en --> works only locally, but not when deployed to firebase functions
localhost/en/<any-page> --> not working also when deployed.
```

next.config.js:

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
  i18n,
}
```

next-i18next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['ar', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'ar',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
};
```

server.js (firebase function):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const app = next({
  dev: false,
  conf: { distDir: '.next' },
});

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextSsrServer = functions
  .runWith({
    memory: '1GB',
  })
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
  });
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextSsrServer"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "runtime": "nodejs14"
  }
}
```

so basically calling this:

```
const router = useRouter()
...
router.push('/', '/', { locale: 'en' });
```

it will route to 404, it should route to `/en` and set locale to `en` correctly.

is there a step missing, or some configuration?

Comment: I'm maving the same issue. Did you fin a solution?

Comment: I am also experiencing this when deploying to Firebase - did you find a resolution?

Comment: I migrated to Vercel, Firebase integration with Next.js still have a lot of issues so I recommend migrating to Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

It now works with the new firebase <-> next integration ;-)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs

Comment: We d'ont need their integragtion framework because it makes a huge of erros. We need to apply some configuration on firebase.json if someone have an idea plz